# Значение слова "ренки" ("ремки")

Tags: значение-слов

Попалась совершенно замечательная песня Уральских пельменей [Уральские пельмени - Песня про бабушку | Блог joshuan.ru](http://www.joshuan.ru/post/14451343121) :) . Большинство слов нашёл, а **ренки** - нет. Что это?

*Вы поди взопрели в своих **ренках***

Comment: Здорово, спасибо!
У большинства в тексте песни через н :)

Comment: Кстати, лирическое наблюдение. Откуда, спрашивается, городской образованный человек знает такие слова? А они вполне ложатся на слух.

Comment: Эти слова говорили наши бабушки и говорят сейчас в небольших городах и поселениях Урала и прилежащих областей, например Кировской. Как они ласкают слух... Баская песня.

Comment: В тексте этой песни еще одна опечатка. Разшопелились. Правильно расшоперились. Трудно писать такие слова правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ре**м**ки - это пренебрежительное название любых тряпок. Например, старая одежда.

Comment: Вот, с буквой "м" стало понятней, в таком виде слово знакомое.

Answer (score 0):

**Вы, поди, взопрели в своих ремках.**
(В данном контексте [**поди**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/278346) — это вводное слово, выделяется запятыми.)

В словаре [**Даля**](http://www.sci.aha.ru/ALL/SLOV/voc.php?typ=1&txt=%D0%C5%CC%C5%CD%DC) (в статье РЕМЕНЬ):
**Ремок**, рямок, сев. вост. рё(о)мух, ре(о)муха вят. ремошина, ремушка, ремуга вологодск. вят. лоскут, тряпица, ветошка, лохмотье, обноски, рваная одежа, рубище.

[**Большой словарь русских поговорок**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/7966/%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%9A):
**РЕМОК**
**Трясти ремками.** *Сиб. Неодобр.* Носить рваную, грязную одежду, ходить в лохмотьях.
**Грязный ремок.** *Арх. Бран.* О человеке, вызывающем резко отрицательные эмоции, осуждение.
**Ремок на ремке.** *Сиб. Пренебр.*
1. О рваной одежде.
2. О человеке, одетом в лохмотья.

**Ремки, ремьё** (мн. ч.) — лохмотья, отрепье ([**Бажов**](http://lukoshko.net/content/dictionary.htm)).

*Это что же — у нее там горы шмотья, а она Машкины **ремки** донашивает?*
Е. Бронникова. Медвежий угол

*Ниночка же только глазом зыркнула, а потом под нуль сняла у Розы волосы, можно сказать, соскоблила их до белого цвета кожи, одела девчонку черт знает в какие **ремки**, посадила на тачку и отвезла в неизвестном направлении.*
Г. Щербакова

*— (...) Вон там штучки какие! Только барам да купцам впору покупать. С нашим-то **ремьём** не наденешь эко место. А люди деньги бы дали. Разоставок тебе.*
П. Бажов